# How to query date and add 3 day in the result?

Tags: mysql, date-arithmetic

I have the follow query who allow me to get the expiration date of plan subscription of my site:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( `expiry_date`, '%d %m %Y' )
FROM `plan_cbsubs_subscriptions` 
WHERE `user_id` = '[user_id]'
```

So if the plan subscription end the next 27 July, the above query return "27 07 2013". Now my goal is to modify this query for add 3 more day for finally return "30 07 2013" even if the real value is well "27 07 2013".

I suppose is possible to add in the query +3 somewhere, but I don't know the correct syntax.

Comment: The term for this is "date arithmetic" next time it comes up and you need to Google for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(`expiry_date`,INTERVAL 3 DAY), '%d %m %Y' )
FROM `plan_cbsubs_subscriptions` 
WHERE `user_id` = '[user_id]';
```

to subtract 3 days:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(`expiry_date`,INTERVAL 3 DAY), '%d %m %Y')
FROM `plan_cbsubs_subscriptions`
WHERE `user_id` = '[user_id]';
```

you can find more information here: **[MySQL DateAdd](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)**

Comment: I tested your solution but this don't work at my side. Syntax error somewhere ? The "Bohemian" solution work but I don't see how to substract.. Any clue ?

Comment: Great your solution work...but now I lost my format %d %m %Y and your code display 2013-11-14 18:45:33. I tried to add the code but I don't see the correct syntax.

Comment: Now it should work. I'm sorry but at this moment I haven't a database to test.

Comment: Your crazy? That me I'm sorry to annoy you with my newbie question. You rock.. your solution is exactly what I needed. Many thank

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(`expiry_date`, INTERVAL 3 DAY) , '%d %m %Y' ) 
FROM `plan_cbsubs_subscriptions` 
WHERE `user_id` = '[user_id]'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ADDDATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( ADDDATE(`expiry_date`, 3), '%d %m %Y' ) 
FROM `plan_cbsubs_subscriptions` 
WHERE `user_id` = '[user_id]'
```

Fyi `ADDDATE()` will accept negative numbers if you want to subtract days:

```
ADDDATE(`expiry_date`, -3) -- 3 days before
```

Mysql also has `SUBDATE()`, so you can also do:

```
SUBDATE(`expiry_date`, 3) -- 3 days before
```

Comment: Excellent...and if I need to do the opposite that mean remove 3 days ?

Comment: Either multiply the second argument by -1, or use subdate, I suppose?

Comment: Sorry I don't see what you mean. Could you write an example please ?